# MSSQL Sql tuning advisor - in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In Microsoft SQL Server; there is a 'SQL Tuning Advisor' where you can feed it a query and it will analyze it and offer you suggestions on indexing. Is there something like this for mysql that I can use from phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 3):

Add EXPLAIN to the front of a SELECT statement and run it from the Query tab. It will tell you which indexes it plans to use. You then need to make a judgement call if you can create a better index for it.

Comment: yes. I was aware of the 'explain' syntax. Wanted a ready made solution like MSSQL :)

Comment: Gotcha. I dont typically do my optimizations by hand so you will have to wait and see what someone else says. Sorry I couldnt be of more help.

Comment: Oops. Meant to say "I typically do"

Comment: i am looking for the same as @shergill

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has a query profiler, see this article: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html

And dbForge has graphical front end for that, see: http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/features.html#profiler

I don't think there's any tool that will suggest indexes unless you count the code monkeys at SO.